# Converting a pandas column type inside a class

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have scraped some tables from the web that stored into dataframes. I built a class where I just want to give general summary of these dataframes. However, I have a method in my class that does not work simply because in cannot convert the columnvalue in float. I have the following:`Column 'PTS' has dtype object, cannot use method 'nlargest' with this dtype`.

Here is sample of what I have done:

```
class CurrentState:
   def __init__(self,df, year):
       self.df=df
       self.year=year
    
  def info(self):
      print (self.df.info()) 
        
  def top_performer(self, n, col):
    
      self.df[col]=self.df[col].astype(float)# line posing problem
    
      print (self.df[['Player',col]].nlargest(n,col))
```

However, outside my class I have a similar function:

```
def func(n, col):
    df1999[col]=df1999[col].astype(float)
    print(df1999[['Player',col]].nlargest(n,col))
```

that works perfectly fine.

I have scraped the data from here: 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_per_game.html'

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your dataframe that you are passing to this class? So that we can try and reproduce this issue at our ends also.

Comment: Does your 'func' function works on the column 'PTS' ?

Comment: @jlesueur yes. absolutely

Comment: Ok. So, without a subset of your data, it will difficult to help you.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I am doing this right now. Do you think it is because of this warning message `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` because I have exactly the same code. it works for the function although it appears but does not  work inside the class at all and does not appear.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I have updated the post with the link where you can have a sample of the data

Comment: @jlesueur data link is now being provided

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a problem due to scraping.
If you look at the table, you'll see there are intermediate headers in it.
As Pandas can't convert letters to floats, it returns you an error.
So, you just have to remove those lines.
Here is a working code :

```
import pandas as pd

class CurrentState:
    def __init__(self,df, year):
        self.df=df
        self.year=year

    def info(self):
        print (self.df.info()) 

    def top_performer(self, n, col):
        self.df[col]=self.df[col].astype(float)
        print (self.df[['Player',col]].nlargest(n,col))
year = '2018'
df = pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_' + year + '_per_game.html')
df = df[0]
df = df.loc[df.Player != 'Player', :].copy()

test = CurrentState(df, year)
test.top_performer(3, 'PTS')
```

Comment: No. This is not the problem. I polished my dataframes before I built my class. Plus, as I said this works perfectly fine on the function. Thanks for trying

Comment: And if you try to run the code I posted, do you get also an error ?

Comment: yes I do. I do not think you run your code yourself :)

Comment: Of course I have run the code and here is the result I get for 2018 : ```Player   PTS
241   James Harden  30.4
154  Anthony Davis  28.1
315   LeBron James  27.5
```

Comment: I have edited my answer with the full code I have used. Do you still get an error with this code.If yes, could you precise your Pandas version ?

Comment: I have seen the error in my code. it was not in the sample I provided. Thanks